# autoincrement value on click asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Problem is that i want to auto-increment a value everytime user click the button, i've tried this with and without an updatepane, i have also googled and come up with nothing. Everytime someone clicks the button the number is auto increment and assigned to a label. Can someone help me out please any help is appreciated, i will be later using number to store in SQL database.

The Default.asp page.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <fieldset>
            <legend>UpdatePanel</legend>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Panel created."></asp:Label><br />
            </fieldset>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = autogen.ToString();
    autogen++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to store a variable during postback you should store it in **ViewState**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["autogen"] = 0;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var autogen = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["autogen"]);
    Label1.Text = autogen.ToString();
    ViewState["autogen"] = autogen + 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick reply. When i type the code you just put on here i get the erorr: The operand of an increment or decrement opeartor must be a variable, property or indexer. This is shown on the ((int) section of the code ((int)ViewState["autogen"])++

Comment: Hey thanks again. I just removed ViewState["autogen"] = 0 from page_load function and its working the way i want. Thank you for the help.